# Content of previous post is there when I click "ask (new) question"

Tags: bug

Lately whenever I'm going to create new post I see in the textboxes (title and content, in case it is a question) my latest post.

I understand that sometimes the content gets saved as a draft, but lately I'm going to create a new question and I see the interface with the content of my latest question (even if that question has been posted), and I need to **discard** to clean the form and start fresh.

I don't know if others are experiencing the same or if it is just me or if it's a know bug, but I'm posting here just in case.

Comment: Not sure if this will help -- maybe it's already obvious to you -- but I imagine there's some javascript involved.  // I wasn't sure if you restarted your browser and your computer, and if so, if the behavior you described continued. // I suppose you could also select all and delete.

Comment: I didn't delete the cache or anything, but I actually stopped seeing it. I'll leave the bug "open" a little bit longer and probably will delete it in a couple days if I can't reproduce. Thanks!

Comment: I could not reproduce it, but hlecuanda also [reported it](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/qu%C3%A9-significa-como-agua-para-chocolate/17109#comment31314_17109). I could not find any related posts in [meta.se].

Comment: @fedorqui I created a [new question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/20604/5481) last night and didn't reproduce for the second time in a row. I didn't know other users were experiencing the same. I was going to delete this post, but since others are experiencing it as well I'll just post an answer explaining that seems to be non-reproducible, for me at least. That way others can report if they experience the same.

Comment: I was able to produce this anomaly as follows: I started to write a question earlier in the day, and did not hit "submit."  Later, in a new tab, I begin to write a different question -- but the text from the first one popped up when I hit "Ask a Question."  I wonder if you had another tab still open, as I did?

Comment: @aparente001 this is a different thing. This is a feature implemented after the request in [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/209901): _If you start asking a question, but do not successfully submit, you will see your last saved question draft the next time you visit the ask a question page_. Note also they mention that _Drafts will be automatically cleared after a week_.